# How do I show that a 5 degree reducible polynomial must be divisible by some second degree irreducible polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I need to show that if I have a reducible polynomial $f\in \mathbb{F}_{3}[X] $ of degree $5$ with no roots. Then there exists a monic irreducible polynomial of degree 2 dividing f.

---

My attempt:

$\mathbb{F}_{3}[X]$ is a unique factorization domain, so f can be factored uniquely by irreducible elements.
If f is factored by two polynomials $f=q_1 q_2$, then it needs to satisfy $\deg(f)=\deg(q_1)+\deg(q_2)=5$.
So if $p_n$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree n, then f can be factored in two ways:
$f=p_1p_4$ or $f=p_2p_3$

(But do we don't know anything about the multiplicity of the roots? So couldn't it in theory be factored as a multiple of the same degree polynomial? For example 1 one degree and 2 second degree polynomials?)

I'm somehow supposed to conclude that the only way it can be factored is by $f=p_2p_3$ and thus there must be a second-degree polynomial dividing f (since it is a factor of a second degree). But how do I draw this conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the polynomial is reducible, it can be factored as $f=pq$ with $0\leq \deg(p),\deg(q)\lt \deg(f)$. In this case, $\deg(f)=5$. Moreover, you know that $f$ does **not** have any degree $1$ factors, since it has no roots and roots correspond to degree $1$ factors.

Now, the factorization of $f$ into irreducibles will correspond to a partition of $5$, given by the degrees of the irreducibles. The partitions of $5$ are:
$$\begin{align*}
5 &= 5\\
5 &= 4+1\\
5 &= 3+2\\
5 &= 3+1+1\\
5 &= 2+2+1\\
5 &= 2+1+1+1+1\\
5 &= 1+1+1+1+1.
\end{align*}$$

Of these, only two of them correspond to factorizations with no factor of degree $1$, and one of those two corresponds to the case where $f$ is irreducible. That leaves only one possibility.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I think I forgot that f doesn't have any roots along the way.

Comment: Just to be sure. What are the reason that a 1st degree factor corresponds to a root? 

If I think on regular polynomials, then it makes sense. Because from the fundamental theorem of algebra, a polynomial can be factored into it's roots. and the factors will be of the form $(x-\alpha)$ which is first degree polynomial.

But is there another explanation? Especially since in algebra we are dealing with all kinds of polynomials (Or should I say all kind of rings).

Comment: @sjm23: What is a “regular polynomial”, and how does it differ from a polynomial? You have polynomials over a field. The Factor Theorem holds, which tells you that $f(a)=0$ if and only if $x-a$ divides $f(x)$. And if $bx-c$ is a factor of $f$, $b\neq 0$, then $f(x) = (bx-c)q(x)$ for some $q(x)$, and then what happens when you evaluate at $\frac{c}{b}$?